# Formatting Problem Date with DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I want to display a date with this format :

- MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt

for example :

- 01/04/2011 03:34:03 PM

but I have a problem with the following code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        string displayedDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(displayedDate);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

displays :

> 01/04/2011 **12**:00:00 AM

instead of

> 01/04/2011 **00**:00:00 AM

Anyone knows why ?

Thank you !

Comment: Well in the AM/PM system midnight is represented as 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: Ok, here was the confusionn. I thought midnight was represented as 00:00:00 AM instead of 12:00:00 AM :-/

Comment: That's a reasonable confusion. In the United States, a 12-hour format is far more popular, where 12:00 AM is midnight. As I understand, most everywhere else, a 24-hour format is preferred for its lack of ambiguity. Under that system, midnight is indeed 0:00 (with no need for an AM/PM specifier). Anyway, glad to see your problem is resolved!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Because you've specified a 12-hour clock format instead of a 24-hour format.**

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for the `DateTime.ToString` method gives a full table of format specifiers and what they mean. The choices for hour are as follows:

```
"h"     The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12.
"hh"    The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.
"H"     The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23.
"HH"    The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
```

So, instead of the `hh` custom format specifier, you need to use `HH`. Change this line:

```
string displayedDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

to this:

```
string displayedDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have specified that you want a 12-hour format instead of a 24-hour, that's why. You should use `HH`for 24-hours. Please see the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). This should work for you:

```
string displayedDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I know I've chosen a 12h format. In this format we write "midnight" as 12h00 AM ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change 'hh' to 'H' in your ToString() call.

Comment: Yeah, getting a little tired and read that it needed to be switched the other way around.  Somehow, that translated to changing to 'h'.